# Entity Framework Multiplicity Constraint

Tags: ef-code-first

I have the following (simplified) class structure:

```
public class Foo
{
    public ObservableCollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Baz MyBaz { get; set; }    
}

public class Baz
{
    public ObservableCollection<Quux> Quuces { get; set; }
}
```

Using Entity Framework Code First, I initialize an instance of Foo with new (POCO) children.

If every `Quuces` collection is empty, SaveChanges() works just fine.  However, if any `Quuces` collection contains a Quux, I get:

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Baz_Quuces_Source' of the
>   relationship 'My.Model.Baz_Quuces' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

I have not explicitly configured any of the relationships in my model.

What is happening to cause this?

Comment: where's the `Quux`? And on a side note, you shouldn't mix Observable (i'm guessing related to gui view model or something) and the model (though you might have something else you need this for, that is legitimate).

Comment: @NSGaga: Assume Quux just has an Id and a string property (the real object isn't much more complex than that).  Why not mix EF and Observable?  It's called "persistence ignorant" for a reason.  There should be a business layer that implements business rules, not special copies of objects *for the sole purpose* of presentation or persistence (not arguing though that it can be legitimate to have UI-only objects, just saying one should not be forced by the architecture to create them artificially).

Comment: I'm not entering the discussion, it's personal preference and it's your code:), and I don't have the 'context' here. Speaking of which, you'd need to provide a full example to reproduce, this works just fine with almost exact data I have.